# Raspberry Pi Model B+ pins not working with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: gpio, ubuntu, pi-b+

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on Raspberry Pi Model B+ and everything worked fine. However I found out that the pins are not functioning. I tested it with a multimeter, and even the Vcc pins (5v, 3.3v) do not have the required voltage.

Is there a way to get it working?

---Edited---
I was trying to connect the Raspberry pi to an arduino via RS485 network. Raspberry Pi is the master and the arduino is the slave. I connected a Max485 ttl to RS485 module to the Raspberry and found out that it didn't work. Then only I checked the voltages just to make sure. Turns out even the Vcc pins don't work. I'm not sure whether this is because I'm running ubuntu 14.04 instead of raspbian

Comment: What voltage are you reading, if you are not getting "the required voltage"?

Comment: It's actually closer to zero. ( 0.001v - 0.002v )

Comment: What are you running your Pi off? And are you sure you have set the GPIO pins correctly

Comment: I was trying to connect the Raspberry pi to an arduino via RS485 network. Raspberry Pi is the master and the arduino is the slave. I connected a Max485 ttl to RS485 module to the Raspberry and found out that it didn't work. Then only I checked the voltages just to make sure. Turns out even the Vcc pins don't work. I'm not sure whether this is because I'm running ubuntu instead of raspbian

Comment: Those pins should have voltage without a functioning operating system or even an SD card.  They are hardwired to the corresponding supply rails, so if you aren't getting a reading from them something is very wrong.

Comment: What make of Max485 TTL converter? How did you connect the Max485 2 TTL converter? It is possible that the TTL levels of the converter could have damaged the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Can you clarify where and how you are measuring Vcc ?  also, is your Raspberry Pi booting correctly (and it's just the GPIO pins that you believe are not working) ?   Software/OS should not affect the +5v supply on the GPIO header...